# Mean squared error and Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: probability

How do I prove the following using Chebyshev's inequality?

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables satisfying that $\mathbb{E}\left[(Y-X)^2\right]=0$, then $P(X\neq Y)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that in this case [*Markov's inequality*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality) is more appropriate. Let $\varepsilon > 0.$ Then $\mathbb{P}(\vert X - Y \vert \geq \varepsilon) = \mathbb{P}(\vert X - Y \vert^2 \geq \varepsilon^2) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[(X - Y)^2]}{\varepsilon^2} = 0.$ Thus the sets $\vert X - Y \vert^{-1}([\varepsilon, \infty))$ have probability $0$ and are nested. It follows that $\mathbb{P}(\vert X - Y \vert \neq 0) = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \mathbb{P}(\vert X - Y \vert \geq \varepsilon) = 0,$ i.e. $\mathbb{P}(X \neq Y) = 0.$ I hope this helps. :)